# Application.filesearch in Excel 2007 w/loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I've done several searches and I'm having trouble to find the right code when using the now non-existent .filesearch - I've looked into using both Dir and FileSystemObject but with nothing short of confusion when using a loop after the search... I'm hoping you might be able to help me come to an easier conclusion!

In short, my current code searches a folder for all excel files, and opens the first, does what it needs to do with it, closes it, and opens the next searched file. Thanks in advance!

```
FilePath = "S:\My\File\Path"
FileSpec = ".xls"

Set FS = Application.FileSearch
    With FS
        .LookIn = FilePath
        .Filename = FileSpec
        .Execute
    End With

For b = 1 To FS.FoundFiles.Count
    StrFile = FS.FoundFiles(b)

Set mobjXL = New Excel.Application
With mobjXL

    .Visible = False

'REST OF CODE HERE

next b
```

Comment: what kind of problem you encountered when using `Dir()` function. Show the code you have which will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you pointed in the right direction:

```
Sub Your_Sub()

Dim FSO as Object
Dim FSO_FOLDER AS Object
Dim FSO_FILE as Object
Dim FILE_PATH as String
Dim FILE_EXT as String

FILE_PATH = "S:\My\File\Path"
FILE_EXT = "xls"

''Create FileSystem Objects
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FSO_FOLDER = FSO.GetFolder(FILE_PATH)

If FSO_FOLDER.Files.Count > 0 Then

    ''Loop through each File in Folder    
    For Each FSO_FILE IN FSO_FOLDER.Files

       ''Test extension
       If FSO.GetExtensionName(FSO_FILE.Name) = FILE_EXT Then
           ''Do your thing here
       Else:End if

    Next

Else

Msgbox "No Files Found at " & FILE_PATH

End If

Set FSO = Nothing
Set FSO_FOLDER = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This has worked exactly right as intended, I didn't even have to mess around with a single thing - Absolutely legendary, I can't thank you enough! This has been bugging me for days!

Answer (score 1):

For those that want to make old code that rely on `Application.FileSearch` work again with as little modification as possible, here a class that you can use as a replacement:

https://github.com/MonsieurV/VBA.Application.FileSearch

All you have to do is replacing your `Set fs = Application.FileSearch` by:

```
Dim fs As YtoFileSearch
Set fs = New YtoFileSearch
```

And use it as usual :

```
With fs
    .NewSearch
    .LookIn = "D:\User\Downloads\"
    .fileName = "*.pdf"
    If .Execute() > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Found these PDF files:"
        For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
           Debug.Print .FoundFiles(i)
       Next
    Else
        Debug.Print "Nothing found"
    End If
End With
```

If you don't have legacy code issues, better use directly `Scripting.FileSystemObject` or `Dir()` (see [UberNubIsTrue answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17673593/1956471))